# Clang thread safety analysis with C++ standard library

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, clang

This describes how static thread safety analysis can be done with annotations in C++: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html

How can I use this with standard types like std::mutex and std::lock_guard?

The example code of mutex.h annotates a custom interface. Do I have the type "Mutex" which is defined there and implement a class using std::mutex with the annotated methods or does Clang bring annotated types somehow?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use standard types.  Best way to find out is to compile a little sample and see what happens.

Comment: It prints a warning that I want to use std::mutex which needs the capabilities or something.

Comment: Maybe it uses the wrong stdlib from GCC instead of Clang?

Comment: I don't see why it would work with `<mutex>` unless you mark it up.  You'd also have to mark up `unique_lock` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent versions of clang, you probably don't have to wrap std::mutex anymore, because the thread-safety annotations are [included since March 15, 2016](https://reviews.llvm.org/D14731).

> This adds clang thread safety annotations to std::mutex and
>   std::lock_guard so code using these types can use these types directly
>   instead of having to wrap the types to provide annotations. These checks
>   when enabled by -Wthread-safety provide simple but useful static
>   checking to detect potential race conditions.
>
> See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html for details.

So simply having `-Wthread-safety` should be enough.

Comment: This only works with `libc++`. For other implementations, like `libstdc++`, a straightforward and brute-force way is to add a class wrapper. An example can be found in the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html#mutex-h).

Answer (score 2):

Implement the interface described in the supplied mutex.h file, and use the std::mutex class to do so. I.e here is a half-finished implementation:

Minor change to [mutex.h](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html#mutexheader) file to include a std::mutex object

```
class CAPABILITY("mutex") Mutex {
private:
  std::mutex std_mutex;
public:
  // Acquire/lock this mutex exclusively.  Only one thread can have exclusive
  // access at any one time.  Write operations to guarded data require an
  // exclusive lock.
```

Then implement the rest in mutex.cpp

```
#include "mutex.h"

void Mutex::Lock(){
  this->std_mutex.lock();
}

void Mutex::Unlock(){
  this->std_mutex.unlock();
}

bool Mutex::TryLock(){
  return this->std_mutex.try_lock();
}
```